# Fewer queries on Rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application I have a header that has many rules, since I have many types of profiles.

I want to make just *one* query (maybe two) to get the user and make all the checks that I need

In my application controller I have this method:

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

To check the current user, but I keep calling it on my header.html.erb, if I check it, like, 10 times, I will do 10 queries...

As far as I know when I first call `current_user` I would get a variable `@current_user` to use. But this is clear for me when I have a controller. I call `current_user` and on my view I just check `@current_user.something`. since /layouts/_header.html.erb doesn't have a controller, how can I do this ?

Comment: What you are doing is correct. But use `current_user` in your views, not `@current_user`. It will not perform 10 queries if you call it 10 times; it will perform one query the first time, and then simply load the variable `@current_user` the next 9 times.

Comment: What makes you think you're performing 10 queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have should not perform multiple queries *if* the lookup is successful -- it will set `@current_user` to the return value of the query and then just return that in the future. However, if no user is found, `@current_user` will be initialized to `nil` and so additional calls to `current_user` *will* execute the query again.

One possible workaround is to used the `defined?` operator like so:

```
def current_user
  return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
  @current_user = User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

However I don't love this implementation, because if *anything* defines `@current_user` in the current closure, then this will return the value whether the lookup has been done or not. You could also set *another* variable that tracks whether the current user has been looked up and only execute the query if it has, but that seems ugly to me, too.

For a more robust solution to this general problem, see the [memoist](https://github.com/matthewrudy/memoist) gem. Or better yet, have you considered whether [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and/or [warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden) might be right for your authentication needs?

Answer (score 0):

> since /layouts/_header.html.erb doesn't have a controller, how can I do this ?

Your layouts *do* have controllers. It's impossible for them to be rendered otherwise.

What you're doing now will work as it's written, and it *will* minimize the number of queries, and your layout files *will* have access to the `current_user` helper, provided you've made it available to your views via `helper_method :current_user` in your controller.

There's really nothing wrong with your code, whatsoever; all the problems you think you're having, you're probably not really having.

Answer (score 0):

From the  following

" **I have a header that has many rules, since I have many types of profiles**"

I guess you are verifying multiple conditions based on user role. If my assumption is correct then

Better create separate partials for each role.For example if you have admin role then

create partial in layouts/_admin.html.erb

Then you can include it as

```
<%= render "layouts/" +  current_user.role %>
```